# Will SSD makes software installation/drive re-imaging faster?

Tags: ssd

Given that there is not much of a difference between entry-level [mechanical drives](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/2009-3.5-desktop-hard-drive-charts/h2benchw-3.12-Avg-Write-Throughput,1013.html) and [SSD](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/ssd-charts-2010/Fresh-state-Throughput-Write-Average,2314.html) based on average write throughput, I'm wondering if switching to SSD will make OS installation (or software installation in general) faster*? Will SSD make a full drive re-image faster*?

*Provided that the installation media/image is also placed on an SSD drive (not on a DVD-drive/network location).

PS: I am tasked to make a Cost-benefit analysis for my group on the benefit of SSDs with regards to installation and re-imaging. Installation because we are currently testing our installers and imaging because we need to re-image the test machines after testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the newer ones are faster than your regular hard drive. Even the entry levels. Is it going to be faster for installing ? yes.

But generally you have to bear in mind when it comes to SSD's : What do I need ?

- Fast random access times ? (quickly reading) SSD
- Storage ? mechanical drives
- Heavy writing ?  mechanical drives, even with TRIM you will face degredation over time. (except if you are running enterprise grade SSD, which will degrade a lot slower)

The "main" advantage proclaimed by SSD, is that even when writing fails you can still read. But there have been people here that have seen SSD's fail completely. Chances of that happening with entry level SSD's is greater than with enterprise grade SSD's.

If you just need to write something fast, get yourself some fast mechanical drives and put them in RAID. (if we are talking servers).

If we are talking consumer grade pc's or workstations. I'd take SSD if you do not need a lot of storage. Not only because your imaging will be quite fast. But it also works a lot faster. This is also a better work environment for the one using the computer.

My final answer is : will a SSD make a full drive re-image faster ?

Yes.